# ¿Cómo compilar el proyecto una vez y enlazarlo al compilar otros proyectos?

Tags: gcc, make

Tengo el siguiente problema, asumiendo que la estructura de mi proyecto es la siguiente (`/` es la raíz).

```
/bin                   # Directorio vacío, es la salida del makefile.
/include/*.h           # assembler.h core.h utils.h, Todos los headers estan aquí.
/src/assembler/*.c     # assembler.c tokenizer.c y otras herramientas del ensamblador.
/src/core/*.c          # utils.c core.c y todos los ficheros del núcleo compartido.
/src/machine/*.c       # bla.c foo.c .... Todos los ficheros de la máquina virtual.
```

Todos los proyectos bajo `/src` tienen como dependencia el proyecto `core`, pero tienen acceso a las cabeceras del directorio `/include`

Utilizando `GNU make` necesito poder compilar sólo uno de los proyectos en los que estoy trabajando, sin necesidad de alterar otros proyectos, hasta ahora he utilizado el siguiente `Makefile`:

```
# #$@% Makefile
CC=gcc
FLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -std=c11 -O3
INCLUDES=-Iinclude

checkbin:
    # Ensure bin is there.
    @if [ ! -e "bin" ]; then mkdir "bin"; fi

assembler: checkbin # First check for binaries folder.
    $(CC) -o bin/assembler $(INCLUDES) $(FLAGS) src/core/*.c src/assembler/*.c

vm: checkbin
    $(CC) -o bin/vm $(INCLUDES) $(FLAGS) src/core/*.c src/machine/*.c

clean:
    @if [ -e "bin" ]; then \
        rm -rf "bin"; \
    fi

default: assembler # set assembler to default...
```

El `Makefile` actualmente hace el trabajo, pero hace *mucho* trabajo; está recompilando el `core` cada vez que voy a compilar algún otro proyecto como `machine` o `assembler`.

Para compilarlos por separado sé que debo utilizar el flag `-c` de `gcc`, pero al introducir varios archivos con este flag, no me permite utilizar el flag `-o` para especificar la salida, por ejemplo:

```
$(CC) -c $(FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) /src/core/*.c 
# Si intento poner -o "bin/core" en este caso, me arroja error
```

¿Cómo puedo mover los archivos compilados del proyecto *dependencia*, para este caso `core` en su respectivo directorio `/bin/core` para que pueda ser utilizado posteriormente para compilar cualquier otro proyecto?

Por ejemplo:

```
/bin/core/utils.o
/bin/core/core.o
```

Y se enlaza con la siguiente instrucción:

```
# Asumiendo los valores puestos arriba:
assembler: checkbin
    @if [ ! -e "bin/assembler" ]; then mkdir "bin/assembler"; fi
    # ... <- instrucción que pondrá los .o en el directorio /bin/assembler/*.o
    $(CC) -o /bin/assembler/assembler /bin/core/*.o /bin/assembler/*.o
    # Sólo necesitamos enlazar los archivos objeto.
```

Comment: Luego me exiendo. ¿ Has intentado poner un Makefile en el directorio `core`, y llamarlo con `Makefile -C directorio ?

Comment: Sí, mi idea principal era esa antes de postear la pregunta, pero el proyecto en general es grande así que poner un `makefile` por carpeta no es una opcion...

Comment: Sólo necesito que el contenido de `/bin/core` sea estático hasta que yo haga alguna modificación en ese proyecto y lo recompile.

Comment: Tendrás tus motivos, pero poner un Make por directorio es mucho *mas mejor* que un solo Make *gigantesto*. Y mas fácil de reutilizar.

Comment: Creo que es porque `gcc -c <archivos>` arrojará más de un archivo que tendré que mover al directorio `/bin` de alguna forma para luego poder enlazar los `.o` con otros proyectos .

Comment: El fallo está en `vm: XXX`. Toma `vm` como **un archivo en el directorio actual**, que **nunca será generado**; por eso siempre lo recompila. No estoy seguro, pero, ¿ puedes ponerlo como `bin/vm: XXX` ?

Comment: El makefile compila actualmente :( pone el ejecutable en `/bin`, con nombre `vm`, el problema es que compila `core` y `vm` cada vez que lo ejecuto, necesito solo compilar los cambios a `vm` y enlazarlo con los objetos de `core`

Comment: A eso me refiero con lo del fallo, no a que no compile (no me he explicado bien): como nunca generas los archivos `vm` y `assembler` **en el directorio actual**, siempre intenta crearlos, y siempre los  recompila. Intenta poniendo como *target* la ruta relativa: `bin/assembler: XXX` y `bin/vm: XXX`. Si sigue igual, recopilando siempre, habrá que indicar las dependencias exactas en cada *target*.

Comment: Una línea como `$(CC) -o bin/vm $(INCLUDES) $(FLAGS) src/core/*.c src/machine/*.c` compila todos los `*.c`. Deberías tener reglas (posiblemente implícitas) para compilar de `*.c` a `*.o`, y a partir de ahí, de `<lo_que_necesites>.o` a `vm`.

Comment: Recomiendo como lectura: "Recursive make considered harmful": http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solucion basica era como describia Trauma en su comentario, para ello tuve que re-estructurar el proyecto de manera tal que quedara de la siguiente forma:

```
/components/*.h      # Todos los archivos cabecera
/core/bin            # Carpeta que contendra los archivos objeto.
/core/*.c            # Archivos de codigo del core
/core/Makefile       # Makefile del proyecto Core
/hasm/bin        
/hasm/*.c            # Codigo del proyecto assembler
/hasm/Makefile
/machine/bin     
/machine/*.c         # Codigo del proyecto machine
/machine/Makefile
```

Y el `Makefile` lo configure en cada proyecto que necesite de `core` para que verificara si esta compilado y asi copiar sus ficheros objeto, de lo contrario, compila el proyecto. Quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
# hasm makefile.
CC=gcc
FLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -O3 -std=c11 -c
INCLUDES=-I../components
OUTPUT=hasm # Cambia con el nombre del proyecto.

default: build

# Crea un objetivo condicionalmente, si existen los binarios del proyecto Core.
ifeq ("$(wildcard $(ls ../core/bin/*.o 2> /dev/null))","") # Verifica si hay archivos en /core/bin
dependencies:
    @make -C ../core;
else
dependencies:
    @echo "Core good.";
endif

# Mira a ver si existe el foder bin en el directorio actual.
checkbin:
    @if [ ! -e "bin" ]; then mkdir "bin"; echo "Created!"; else echo "Exists!"; fi

# Construye el proyecto.
build: dependencies checkbin 
    @echo "Building project..."
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) src/*.c  # Compila con el flag -c los archivos del proyecto.
    @mv *.o bin/                        # Mueve todos los archivos objeto al folder bin.
    @cp ../core/bin/*.o bin/;           # Copia los archivos de "../core/bin/" a "./bin/"
    $(CC) -o bin/$(OUTPUT) bin/*.o      # Enlaza con gcc.

# Elimina el folder bin y algun .o que quede en el directorio actual.
clean:
    @if [ -e "bin" ]; then rm -rf "bin"; fi
    @if [ -f *.o ]; then rm -f *.o; fi
```

Al hacer `make`, se ejecuta la *receta* `build`, que tiene como pre requisito a `dependencies` y `checkbin`, en `dependencies`, se encarga de llamar a `make -C ../core`, donde la `-C` especifica que el `Makefile` se encuentra en el directorio a su derecha, con esto se compilan las dependencias del proyecto, es decir, `core`.

Luego de eso, procede a la copia de los archivos objeto dentro de la carpeta `/core/bin/` a la carpeta del proyecto que ande trabajando y los enlaza sin problema.

Comment: Me alegra de que lo hayas solucionado. 

Comment: @Trauma Al final me decidí por cambiar la estructura, ahora me cuesta acostumbrarme, ¡Pero funciona! xD